# How to reduce an array of objects on multiple variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I would like to know how to reduce a large array of objects based upon several properties. The array looks like:

```
[{count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:6, district:12, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:14, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"VANDALISM"},
...
{count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:7, district:10, to_timestamp:"2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"ASSAULT"}]
```

Resulting reduced array of objects needs to include the aggregate `count` from every `district` for given crime `type` on any given date (`to_timestamp`); dates are weekly. Something like:

```
[{key: "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT", value: 57, date:"2015/09/23"},
...
  {key: "ASSAULT", value: 77, date:"2016/03/23"}]
```

I'm already using Moment for date conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an object as hash table for the wanted groups (`type` and `to_timestamp`) and use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating the array.

```js
var data = [{ count: 4, district: 19, to_timestamp: "2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type: "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT" }, { count: 6, district: 12, to_timestamp: "2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type: "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT" }, { count: 14, district: 19, to_timestamp: "2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", type: "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT" }, { count: 4, district: 19, to_timestamp: "2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type: "VANDALISM" }, { count: 4, district: 19, to_timestamp: "2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type: "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT" }, { count: 7, district: 10, to_timestamp: "2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type: "ASSAULT" }],
    groupBy = ['type', 'to_timestamp'],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = groupBy.map(function (k) { return a[k]; }).join('|');
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = { key: a.type, value: 0, date: a.to_timestamp.slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/') };
        grouped.push(this[key]);
    }
    this[key].value += a.count;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Can't say that I fully understand it (yet), but it sure does work. Mahalo. Are you able to explain a bit about what is happening on line:
`var key = groupBy.map(function (k) { return a[k]; }).join('|');`

Comment: this line builds a new key with the values of the properties, defined in `groupBy`. for example for the first element, you get for the first property `type` the value `"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"` and for `to_timestamp` the value `"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z"` in an array. this is then joined with `|` and the result for the key is `"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT|2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z"`. this result is used as hash for the object.

Answer (score 2):

but I think you reduce a object will be easier more then a array. after you got a object, you can convert it to a array

This code are just combine the `data` and `type` to the object key. Did not  add `district`.

```js
const object = [{count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:6, district:12, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:14, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"VANDALISM"},
{count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
{count:7, district:10, to_timestamp:"2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"ASSAULT"}]

// reduce a object 
.reduce( ( res, item) => {
  
  const date = moment(item.to_timestamp).format('YYYY/MM/DD')
  const key = item.type + date
  
  if ( !res[key] ) {
    res[key] = {key: item.type, date: date, value: item.count}
  } else {
    res[key]['value'] += item.count
  }
  return res
}, {} )

//get a object, and then the object to array
//console.log(object) 
var result = []
for ( var key in object ) {
  result.push(object[key])
}
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the `reduce` -based answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a simple `Array.prototype.forEach` loop:

```js
var crimes = [
 {count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
 {count:6, district:12, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
 {count:14, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
 {count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"VANDALISM"},
 {count:4, district:19, to_timestamp:"2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"},
 {count:7, district:10, to_timestamp:"2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", type:"ASSAULT"}
];

var dict = {},
 result = [];
crimes.forEach(crime => {
 var date = new Date(crime.to_timestamp);
 date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());
 var hash = crime.type + date.toDateString()
 if (!dict[hash]) {
  dict[hash] = {
   count: crime.count,
   key: crime.type,
   date: date
  };
  result.push(dict[hash])
 } else
  dict[hash].count += crime.count;
});

console.log(result);
```